# Is there a syntax for a "for" loop over words or lines in a variable, that will work unmofdified in both bourne shell and zsh?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, for, bourne-shell

I have a variable that contains a list of strings, one per line, to be looped over in a `for...in...do...done` command.

I move regularly between bourne shell and zsh.  As far as I can understand it, zsh doesnt by default split words out of a a string at newline or whitespace; bourne shell does. So commands like `for list_item in $list; do...` fail in zsh whereas they'd work in bourne shell, or with literal text rather than variable. Ive tried playing with `IFS=` in the command, and quoting the variable, but can't seem to make progress.

Is there a single syntax for a loop over the words/lines in the string, that will work unmodified in both shells, for ease?  if not, what's best practice?

Comment: Do you have some control on that original variable? You say this is a newline-separated list of strings, presumably in one single string. Can it be an array instead? Or anything else deemed more convenient?

Comment: Do you really mean [bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) or do you maybe mean [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) instead? The bourne shell is very old and not often used these days. Bash is not the bourne shell, it is the bourne again shell. And even `sh` on most modern systems is going to be something like `dash` or `bash`.

Comment: I really did mean Bourne shell. I'm using FreeBSD and the /bin/sh is Almquist/ash (basically Debian's dash shell), described as "a clone of SVR3 Bourne Shell".

Comment: OP answered my question above in my (deleted) answer: « In this case the variable contents are indeed generated by processing command output, along the lines of `VAR="$( command /path-to-dir | grep 'stuff' | sed 'expression' )"`. But in other circumstances that can't be assumed. »

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve consistent behavior between bash and zsh by explicitly setting zsh's word-splitting behavior to resemble that of bash with the `shwordsplit` option. For example:

```bash
set -o shwordsplit

var='foo bar baz'
for item in $var; do
    echo "$item"
done
```

This will make zsh perform word splitting based on the Internal Field Separator (`IFS`), as bash does.

Comment: Temporarily setting shell options as a workaround isnt really polite. If something goes wrong, and error trapping isnt 100% perfect, it's got potential to mess with anything else run within the session from then on.

Comment: `set -o shwordsplit` gives an error in shells other than `zsh`. Also in shells other than zsh, you'd need to disable globbing with `set -o noglob`.

Answer (score 1):

The Bourne shell is no longer in use and was pre-POSIX and is not POSIX-compliant. There are shells based on the Bourne shell that are POSIX-compliant: the original Korn shell (before the ksh93 rewrite), as that's what the POSIX specification of sh is based on, and bosh which was based on the OpenSolaris `sh` (itself based on the SysV shell with a few modifications, itself based on the Bourne shell).

FreeBSD's `sh` is based on the Almquist shell (itself a mostly compatible opensource clone of the SysV shell with a few extensions including some from ksh such as `$(...)`), but modified to be made POSIX compliant.

In POSIX `sh`, to loop over lines in a `for` loop, you can't use split+glob, as the newline being a whitespace character, for IFS-splitting any sequence of one or more newlines act as a separator, so something like:

```
IFS='
' # split on newline
set -o noglob # disable the glob part
for line in $multiline_string; do
  printf '<%s>\n' "$line"
don
```

Would skip the empty lines. Also, `zsh` doesn't do splitting nor globbing upon unquoted parameter expansions, so you'd need a `emulate sh` there.

You could construct the `"$@"` array with the lines of `$multiline_string` with something like:

```
NL='
'
set --
while [ -n "$multiline_string" ]; do
  line=${multiline_string%%"$NL"*}
  set -- "$@" "$line"
  multiline_string=${multiline_string#"$line"}
  multiline_string=${multiline_string#"$NL"}
done

for line do
  printf '<%s>\n'
done
```

Or:

```
printf '%s\n' "$multiline_string" | {
  set --
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    set -- "$@" "$line"
  done
  for line do
    printf '<%s>\n' "$line"
  done
}
```

Or you could construct the `for` loop shell code with something like:

```
eval '
  for line in '"$(
    awk -v q="'" -F '\n' -v ORS=' ' -- '
      BEGIN {
        n = split(ARGV[1], line)
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
          gsub(q, "&\\\\&&", line[i])
          print q line[i] q
        }
      }' "$multiline_string")"'; do
    printf "<%s>\n" "$line"
  done
'
```